# How to create a Azure Drive at size of 1T?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I use `cloudDrive.Create(1048576);` since it says size in MB, so 1048576 is 1T

but, the size is 1023.9G 1,099,510,579,712 bytes on the blob file

If mount in Windows Azure, it says 0.99T 1,099,509,497,856 bytes

So, is there a way to create a VHD just on 1T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All mounted and formatted drives have overhead - something has to track partitions, files, MFTs, etc.  That uses storage just like any real drive (remember you are mounting a VHD).

As to why the VHD itself is ~1MB less than a TB - dunno.  Call it a rounding error.